# Use class as generic type parameter in a method

Tags: swift, generics

I am using following generic method to return child classes

```
class SomeClass {

    var childInstance: ParentClass?

    func getClass<T: ParentClass>() -> T? {
        return childInstance as? T
    }

    func usage() {
        if let view: ChildTwo = self.getClass() {
            view.someMethodOfClassTwo()
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to pass class as generic type parameter? so the usage would be **without if statement**, like so:

```
self.getClass(type: ChildTwo)?.someMethodOfClassTwo()
```

Parent/child classes used above are as following:

```
class ParentClass { }
class ChildOne: ParentClass {
    func someMethodOfClassOne() { }
}
class ChildTwo: ParentClass {
    func someMethodOfClassTwo() { }
}
```

**Update**: `ParentClass` is a class, for some reason I cannot use a protocol or change it to a protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. But I'm confused how you are going to use that.

You need to slightly modify the signature of your `getClass<T: ParentClass>() -> T?` function. I've purposefully changed the name of the function too because it doesn't make sense to have a name as `getClass` where you are actually getting child instance.

```
class SomeClass {

    var childInstance: ParentClass?

    func getChild<T: ParentClass>(type: T.Type) -> T? {
        return childInstance as? T
    }

    func usage() {
        if let child = self.getChild(type: ChildTwo.self) {
            child.someMethodOfClassTwo()
        }
    }
}
```

Again you can use it without the `if-let` binding too. But then you've to deal with `optional chaining`:

```
SomeClass().getChild(type: ChildTwo.self)?.someMethodOfClassTwo()
```

Here with `ParentClass` as a class, you get autocompletion as you pass a generic class type which actually doesn't make much of sense:
[image: ParentClass as class]

---

**Edit:**

If you slightly modify the design as `ParentClass` to be a `Parent` protocol, then Xcode autocompletion will suggest you more meaningful signature. See:

```
protocol Parent { }
class ChildOne: Parent {
    func functionOfChildOne() { }
}
class ChildTwo: Parent {
    func functionOfChildTwo() { }
}

class SomeClass {

    var childInstance: Parent?

    func getChild<T: Parent>(type: T.Type) -> T? {
        return childInstance as? T
    }

    func usage() {
        if let child = self.getChild(type: ChildTwo.self) {
            child.functionOfChildTwo()
        }
    }
}
```

And Xcode autocomplete suggests you pass a type that conforms to `Parent` protocol
[image: Parent as protocol]